# Categories labels aren't fit in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have design a GUI which cannot show categories in barh? Can anyone guide?

```
        c = {'Triangle','Square','Round'};
        triangle=66;
        squre=23;
        round=11;
        total=triangle+squre+round;
        percentage = [triangle/total squre/total round/total].*100; 
        set(handles.axes1,'Visible','on');
        cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
        axes(handles.axes1)
        barh(percentage)
        set(gca,'yticklabel',{c{:}})
        axis off
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Do you need the labels of the categories on the Y axis? Then do not turn off the axis! remove `axis off`

Comment: it doesn't show the bar any more if I remove axis off :(